# How to Copy file from apps internal folder before it gets deleted?

Tags: android, apk, decompiling

I am reverse engineering an application for personal use.

The given application creates a file - "a" - inside its data folder in /data/data reads it and then deletes it. I found that out by decompiling the apk.

Is there any way i can copy this file before it gets deleted? (I rooted my phone so i have access to the /data/data folder)

Answer (score 1):

Assuming we are talking about an Android device.

You should use **Frida** (https://www.frida.re/) to **hook** the **unlink** method on your system. As you can see here: http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/unlink.2.html, this method is the underlying UNIX call responsible for deleting an entry in your filesystem.

You could make a **temporary** hook that checks the filename (first argument) and if it contains **/data/data/** then you return instead of actually deleting the file.

```
'use strict';

Interceptor.attach(Module.findExportByName('libc.so', 'unlink'), {
  onEnter(args) {
    /*
     * This code block will be called before the real 'unlink'
     * method. Allowing us to change its behaviour.
     */
    const fileName = Memory.readUtf8String(args[0]);

    if (fileName.indexOf('/data/data/') !== -1) {
      Memory.writeUtf8String(args[0], '/invalid/path');
    }
  }
});
```

It's as simple as that ! If we detect that the file looking to be deleted is in the target directory we pass an **invalid path** to the **unlink** method instead, resulting in the file not being removed from the filesystem.